# Почему не отслеживается знак "Делегат"?

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, знаки

На Stack Overflow существует знак "Делегат":

[image: Описание медали]

У меня уже 8 сообщений на Мете с рейтингом минимум 2 балла, однако знака "Делегат" в списке доступных нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: почему?

**P.S:** Я знаю, что некоторые серебряные знаки не отслеживаются (например, "Инспектор", "Научный ассистент"), но существуют страницы, где процесс их заполнения показывается. "Делегат" не показывается нигде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ есть на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273014/339911). Суть в том, что знак выдаётся за вклад на Мете, и архитектурно базы основного и мета сайтов развязаны, что усложняет отслеживание прогресса. Аналогичное решение по знакам, связанным с чатом.

Comment: Хорошо, а почему этот знак не отслеживается на Мете? Почему это знак SO, а не metaSO?

Comment: @Глеб ответ снова на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246308/339911). Чтобы стимулировать походы с основного сайта на мету.